# EF LINQ Search across Multiple Fields using Multiple Values but they all must occur at least once

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to build a search which allows for multiple individual search keywords that I want to match across multiple fields (each via *Contains*, or *LIKE*). I also want to guarantee that each record returned contains **all** of the search keywords, and not just some of them.

Example Table:

```
# | Color  | Animal   | Car Brand
1 | Orange | Gorilla  | Citroen
2 | Blue   | Cat      | Skoda
3 | Red    | Antilope | Ford
4 | Orange | Cat      | BMW
5 | Grey   | Antilope | BMW
6 | Purple | Gorilla  | Lada
```

Example Searches:

```
"Orange Gorilla" returns record 1.
"Orange BMW" returns record 4.
"Orange" returns records 1 and 4.
"Cat" returns records 2 and 4.
"Ford Antilope" returns record 3.
```

If I just perform a regular Contains-OR lookup, like this:

```
foreach (string searchterm in searchterms)
   color.Contains(searchterm) || animal.Contains(searchterm) || car.Contains(searchterm)
```

then `Orange Gorilla` will return records 1, 4 and 6 instead of only record 1 because record 4 also contains "Orange" (but not Gorilla) and record 6 also contains "Gorilla" (but not Orange).

Thoughts on the most efficient implementation, that is EF/LINQ-to-SQL compatible?

Comment: I'd suggest bringing back too many rows and then checking them locally might be your best option. Otherwise, writing the code to generate the perfect LINQ may end up being tricky.

Comment: That code you wrote won't contain any items. Do you mean `searchterm.Contains()` instead?

Comment: @RufusL that was pseudocode since it isn't material to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the pseudocode you wrote won't contain any items... :)

Comment: @RufusL, added an answer works on the examples you have given

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how efficient it is, but it seems to me you just need to add a condition for each column that checks to see if ***any*** rows contain the search term before using it as a filter.

One way to do that is to get all rows where none of them contain the search term or just those that do contain the search term. I'm really not sure how EF-friendly this would be, but it should return the results you're looking for:

```
var results = table
    .Where(row => !table.Any(r => searchTerm.Contains(r.Color)) || 
                  searchTerm.Contains(row.Color))
    .Where(row => !table.Any(r => searchTerm.Contains(r.Animal)) || 
                  searchTerm.Contains(row.Animal))
    .Where(row => !table.Any(r => searchTerm.Contains(r.CarBrand)) || 
                  searchTerm.Contains(row.CarBrand));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you built the LINQ to count the matched `searchTerm`s?

```
foreach (string searchterm in searchterms)
    f = f + ((color.Contains(searchterm) || animal.Contains(searchterm) || car.Contains(searchterm)) ? 1 : 0)

q = f == searchterms.Count
```

Answer (score 0):

though this is a bit dirty and not that dynamic, this will work on the conditions/table structure you have shown.

*spaces on searches, 3 column look up, should match all conditions*

```
var searchTerm = //user input;

var countSearch = searchTerm.Split().Count(); //splits the search and count how many

var query = tables.AsQueryable();

if (countSearch == 1) // searchTerm will check any rows
{
    query = query.Where(a => 
                             searchTerm.Contains(a.Color) || 
                             searchTerm.Contains(a.Animal) || 
                             searchTerm.Contains(a.CarBrand));
            }
else if (countSearch == 2) //searchTerm will check at least two combinations on rows
{
    query  = query.Where(a => (searchTerm.Contains(a.Color) && searchTerm.Contains(a.Animal)) 
                           || (searchTerm.Contains(a.Color) && searchTerm.Contains(a.CarBrand)) 
                           || (searchTerm.Contains(a.Animal) && searchTerm.Contains(a.CarBrand)));
}
else if (countSearch == 3) //searchTern will check all rows
{
    query = query.Where(a => 
                             searchTerm.Contains(a.Color) && 
                             searchTerm.Contains(a.Animal) && 
                             searchTerm.Contains(a.CarBrand));
}

var results = query.ToList();
```